# Pyplot: How to make a colorbar with a nonlinear scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to add to my plot a `colorbar`, which has a nonlinear scale. For example, for such a plot:

[image]

I would like to have just 5 different colors on the bar on the right-hand side, instead of the gradient (don't pay attention to the plot itself; it's just an example).

I don't want to use `contourf` and would like to find some more general solution.

Comment: You didn't add any code, so it is hard to guess how you are calling things. `cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 5)` would give you a colormap with just 5 colors from viridis. It will still be linear colormap though.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have discrete values in your colorbar, a quick way to do this would be to use the `cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap()` function and pass the name of whatever [colormap class](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#classes-of-colormaps) you are working with, along with the desired number of bins.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

# Random Data Visualation
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
data = np.sin(x) * np.cos(x[:, np.newaxis])

plt.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 5))
plt.colorbar()
plt.clim(-1, 1);
```

[image]

> More documentation on everything color maps in Matplotlib [[here]](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)