# How can I limit the colorbar?

Tags: matplotlib, range, colorbar

I am trying to make a map with this code. But I don't know how to choose the range of the colorbar. I tried with `set_clim(min,max)` but it doesn't work with matplotlib 3.1.

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    cs=ax.contourf(lon, lat, bowenratio, 11, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r)
    ax.coastlines()
    cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal',shrink=0.7)
```

Comment: Does `plt.clim(min, max)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put `plt.clim(min,max)` after your visualization.

You can include the number of bins, based on your range within the `cmap` function as outlined in this example which also has a -1 to 1 range specified within a `plt.clim` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61896135/9022112